# How to install Microsoft Access Database Engine or OLEDB to Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, oledb

I wanted to know how can I install Microsoft Access Database Engine or OLEDB to my azure sql server. I need to read excel file using Stored Procedure in Azure SQL which shows error for missing OLEDB provider. In local system installing Microsoft Access Database Engine setup solved the issue but not sure about azure sql.

Comment: Your purpose is read excel file not csv file using Stored Procedure in Azure SQL database？

Comment: @Leon The - yes

Comment: unfortunatately, there isn't a way can help you achieve that with .xlsx file. Most way all works for local SQL server or csv file, such OPENROWSET. Others have post the same questions in stack overflow, still with now answer. I hope this can be solved by Microsoft in future. But for now, we must be wait. If you need this, I also can post as answer.

Comment: @LeonYue - I do have a idea to import excel file locally and save it to temp table,  then use SQL Command to connect to Azure SQL and then Insert data from temp table. This should achieve it but still haven't tried yet.

Comment: But temp table  will be deleted when the session closed.

Comment: If you tried it and works, please post as the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In short, you cannot. The Azure SQL PaaS offering does not allow for external installations. You will have to use a secondary system to do the transfer of Excel data into SQL Azure DB. If you are just trying to copy the data in SSMS has a powerful import data wizard. If you need an automated process I would check into Data Factory.

Another option would be to run SQL Server in an VM but depending on your database size that may be overkill.

Comment: I need to do some data validation(duplicate check) before insert so wanted to use  SP for that. Is it possible to read excel in my local and then do validation from the Azure SQL database and if validation successful then insert data to Azure SQL database.